# Whatsapp running at startup on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, whatsapp

I have installed the Whatsapp desktop application on windows 10. I downloaded and installed it via the Microsoft Store. I have gone into the startup section on the Task Manager and have stopped the Whatsapp application from starting on windows startup. I have almost all my apps turned off on startup.

But the issue is even though it's disabled on startup whatsapp somehow still runs everytime i restart or turn on my PC. If i go into the background processes section on the task manager i can see whatsapp running. the whatsapp window doesn't open on startup but the app is still running in the background so whenever some sends me a message, if internet on my phone is turned off, i get the message notification on my desktop.

I don't want whatsapp to run on startup. I have couple of occasions i need to use it on PC, and on those occasions i can simply run it.

Any ideas why this is happening or anyways I can permanently disable from running automatically? Thanks.

Comment: Does WhatsApp have a service as well? If so, set the service to _Manual_ - otherwise, you may want to use a Nirsoft or SysInternals program to view all Startup programs, as Task Manager doesn't show all of them _(there's five startup locations, all/each user Startup folder startup, all/each user Registry startup, and Services set to Automatic or Automatic (Delayed Start))_

Comment: Agreed. I use SysInternals Autoruns for this

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for the reply. Nope there is no service running for it whatsapp on in the task manager. Only the process. I have Sysinternals Autoruns but in it there is no entry for whatsapp.

Comment: It isn't clear to me if you have disabled its startup in the WhatsApp setting (three dots menu) "Start WhatsApp at Login".

Comment: @AndrewMorton Inside whatsapp also its disabled. In fact I cant change the setting to enable it even if i wanted to because it has greyed out that option and it says "Go to your computers settings -> Apps -> Startup and enable whatsapp to be started at login"

Comment: @usefulmellow (1) I know it's far from ideal, but would it be too much hassle to uninstall it and then only install it on the occasions you need it? (2) Is there anything that looks like a "WhatsApp helper app" which could be the thing that is starting WhatsApp? (3) Have you tried all the options listed in [How to Add, Delete, Enable, or Disable Startup Items in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2944-add-delete-enable-disable-startup-items-windows-10-a.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the article. Apart from checking the registry and startup folder, i have done the others. I will check those two now. But if it still wont work yes I will remove that app from the PC. I can use the web version when i need to access it from the PC. Also no there is no helper app sort of thing that makes whatsapp run. This was the only app i installed from the microsoft store so i was wondering whether it had to do anything with this. Anyways thanks for the input.

Comment: Is it actually _running_ though? Windows likes to “warm up” UWP applications by starting the process, then suspending it. This isn’t related to autostart. (WhatsApp is a true UWP application.)

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be two places this can be disabled:

1. Open WhatsApp app, then Settings -> Notifications -> "When WhatsApp is closed"
2. Right-click WhatsApp app in Start menu, More -> App Settings -> App Permissions -> Run in Background -> Disabled.

I did both on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Check `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\` for files and check `%PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`. This is where user and system startup shortcuts are put, mainly user created ones, but not always.